# How to extend Unity Application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, extend, urbanairship.com

I know I should post that question at Unity's Q&A but unfortunately they're pretty unresponsive. :P Anyway, Urban Airship requires me to extend **Application** instead of (as usual) **Activity**. Is there any way to do that in Unity?

I tried extending Activity instead but it works only partially. It works and I get notifications on my phone but only when the app is actually running (should work too if it's not) and when I tap the notification it crashes my app. As I've read here: [Re-launching android application when user clicks Urban Airship notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849388/re-launching-android-application-when-user-clicks-urban-airship-notification) the problem was that I extended the Activity instead of Application. If extending Application is impossible in Unity is there any way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found it (should have days ago but google kept giving me wrong results :():
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/126833-Can-the-Application-class-be-overridden-or-extended-in-a-plugin

Comment: @Creator I wanted to then buy I had to wait 2 days and forgot. Thx for reminding me.